# Java: How to check if a generated level is possible?

Tags: java, dictionary, generated

I've created a text based game which automatically generates a map with 10x10 rooms, a few of the rooms are blocked by various debris and I couldn't work out the most efficient way to check if a player can still reach a key and get to the exit without them being cut off from the map.

Currently there's a low chance needed rooms are cut off from the rest of the map, making the level impossible, I thought about checking each adjacent square to the start position, and then repeat and repeat until all of the squares that are accessible are set to 'accessible' in a variable and then if the three objects aren't reachable just regen'ing the map again until they are.
This may be slow if it regens a few times though.

Does anyone have any thoughts on the repetitive part to keep it fast, or a better way of achieving this?

Here's an image of a generated map: #'s are blocked rooms.
http://postimg.org/image/8oo88jxgb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), or some other [pathfinding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Algorithms), to check if there is a way from the room entrance to each object and then discard the invalid rooms. This would probably be a bit slow though, specially if the rooms get bigger or you add more objects.

A better option would be to guarantee by construction that each part of the room can be reached. This can be achieved using [Binary Space Partioning (BSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning). It can be used to create random dungeons while assuring that all the rooms are connected. You can find more information in [this tutorial](http://eskerda.com/bsp-dungeon-generation/).

There is a lot of material about procedurally generated dungeons around. You can check another interesting [tutorial here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-procedurally-generated-dungeon-cave-system--gamedev-10099).

Comment: Ah, I'll take a look at those algorithms and see which would suit me the best. The positions are stored as arrays so it would be tricky as there's no shortest 'distance' for the Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: You can model a matrix as a graph where each position m[i][j] is node with 8 adjacent nodes, which are the positions around it. Going from m[i][j] to m[i+1][j] for example would count as 1 distance unit. I also updated the answer suggesting you check the BSP algorithm.

Comment: I'll give that a go and see how it works out, it will be a little easier since players can't move diagonally.

Answer (score 1):

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time
>   worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times;
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
>   it) in programming.

[Donald Knuth (1974 Turing Award Lecture, Communications of the ACM 17 (12), (December 1974), pp. 667–673)](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Taking Knuth's advice, I recommend implementing the simplest solution that comes to mind (as outlined in the question, for example) and only looking for a more efficient algorithm if that approach turns out to be a bottleneck in the program. If he was right for computers with the performance they had in 1974, he's much more right now ...

Comment: I really only think about efficiency since coming from Game Maker where I didn't care at all about it and by the end it was incredibly slow. Fair point though I can always do it later and being text based only, speeds not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could represent your board as a graph holding a coordinate value as the key and a set of coordinates as the values representing each coordinates neighbors..example `Map<Coordinate, HashSet<Coordinate> = new Hashmap<Coordinate, HashSet<Coordinate>();`. 
Then populate the graph with each coordinate value as a key with their respective neighbors as their values.
Whenever a blocked off room appears, simply remove that coordinate from each of the coordinates neighbors that surround it.

So if you have coordinate (5,5) as a blocked room, you would removed (5,5) from (4,5)s neighbor set, (5,4)s neighbor set, (6,5)s neighbor set, and (5,6)s neighbor set. This would basically not allow you to move through this path any more.

To populate the graph you could use two loops:

```
    for(int r = 0; r <= 10; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c <= 10; c++){
            HashSet<Coordinate> neighbors = new HashSet<Coordinate>();
                 if(r > 0){
                    neighbors.add(new Coordinate(r - 1, c));
                 }
                if(r < 8){
                     neighbors.add(new Coordinate(r + 1, c));
                 }
                if(c > 0){
                    neighbors.add(new Coordinate(r, c - 1));
                 }
                if(c < 8){
                    neighbors.add(new Coordinate(r, c + 1));
                 }
            graph.put((new Coordinate(r,c)), neighbors);
        }
    }
```

I hope this is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array A with a row for each room and a column for each room.

Put a 1 in each i, j (row,column) position if the two rooms are connected.

This matrix( **A** ) is the numeric representation of the graph that is your game, the nodes of the graph are rooms and the edges are doors.

Now take a vector with a length corresponding to the number of rooms you have and fill it with zeros except for a one in the position corresponding to the room you start in. This vector( **P** ) is the number of ways you can get to a given room after 0 transitions. To check if it is possible to get to a given room in ( **n** )transitions simply multiply **P A^n** and look for a non zero value in the position in the vector that represents the given room.

this is a generalization of maths described well here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain